# Odin Error: Fail! (Auth) when trying to change the flash firmware to hongkong TGY from mainland china CHC

Tags: samsung, odin

I want to change the CSC code for my S21 Ultra for less bloatware, and google assistant available.

[image: Firmware I wanted to update:]

[image: my phone current build]

I used Odin v3.13.1, but I tried multiple versions, as well as the patched one, with failure.
Here is the full traceback of the error:

```
    <ID:0/009> Odin engine v(ID:3.1301)..

<ID:0/009> File analysis..

<ID:0/009> Total Binary size: 12081 M

<ID:0/009> SetupConnection..

<ID:0/009> Initialzation..

<ID:0/009> Set PIT file..

<ID:0/009> DO NOT TURN OFF TARGET!!

<ID:0/009> Get PIT for mapping..

<ID:0/009> Firmware update start..

<ID:0/009> NAND Write Start!!

<ID:0/009> SingleDownload.

<ID:0/009> abl.elf

<ID:0/009> xbl.elf

<ID:0/009> FAIL! (Auth)

<ID:0/009>

<ID:0/009> Complete(Write) operation failed.

<OSM> All threads completed. (succeed 0 / failed 1)
```

I also tried unlocking the bootloader, didn't work.